# Result contains obtained parameters? So what?

Tags: isabelle-hol, isar

When proving an existential claim, you can use `rule exI` and exhibit an example; this is a sufficient proof (as you'd expect!). Conversely, if you *have* an existential claim, you can `obtain` a value that satisfies the predicate `by (rule exE)`.

Isabelle/Isar doesn't like it when I mix the two techniques:

```
lemma
  fixes P f
  assumes ‹Ex P› and ‹⋀a. P a ⟹ ∃b. a = f b›
  shows ‹∃a. P a ∧ (∃b. a = f b)›
proof (rule exI)
  from ‹Ex P› obtain a where ‹P a› by (rule exE)
  hence ‹∃b. a = f b› by (rule assms(2))
  with ‹P a› show ‹P a ∧ (∃b. a = f b)› by (rule conjI)
qed
```

> Result contains obtained parameters: `a` 
> Local statement fails to refine any pending goal

This is strange, because Isabelle/HOL has Hilbert's choice function $\varepsilon$ (named `Eps`). So anywhere we find ourselves writing:

```
from ‹Ex P› obtain a where ‹P a› by (rule exE)
```

we could instead write:

```
define a where ‹a = Eps P›
with someI_ex[OF ‹Ex P›] have ‹P a›
  by (rule back_subst[OF _ sym])
```

This substitution works in this case:

```
lemma
  fixes P f
  assumes ‹Ex P› and ‹⋀a. P a ⟹ ∃b. a = f b›
  shows ‹∃a. P a ∧ (∃b. a = f b)›
proof (rule exI)
  define a where ‹a = Eps P› with someI_ex[OF ‹Ex P›] have ‹P a› by (rule back_subst[OF _ sym])
  hence ‹∃b. a = f b› by (rule assms(2))
  with ‹P a› show ‹P a ∧ (∃b. a = f b)› by (rule conjI)
qed
```

I believe this substitution always works. You can't `obtain x where ‹P x› using ‹¬Ex P›`; if "`obtain x where ‹P x›` has a proof" and "`lemma ‹Ex P›` has a proof" really are equivalent, as I suspect, you *should* be able to put any `obtain` proof into this form.

So… why does the "result contains obtained parameters" error message even exist? This seems like an arbitrary limitation, or a [leaky abstraction](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/): what's really going on here?

Answer (score 2):

This one was [already answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24513666/5223757):

> Soundness of natural deduction requires that you get hold of the witness before you open the existential quantifier.

This means you need to place the `rule exI` *after* the `obtain`, like so:

```
lemma
  fixes P f
  assumes ‹Ex P› and ‹⋀a. P a ⟹ ∃b. a = f b›
  shows ‹∃a. P a ∧ (∃b. a = f b)›
proof -
  from ‹Ex P› obtain a where ‹P a› by (rule exE)
  hence ‹∃b. a = f b› by (rule assms(2))
  note conjI[OF ‹P a› this]
  thus ?thesis by (rule exI)
qed
```

`obtain` is defined in Isabelle/Pure/Isar, which does not yet have Hilbert's choice function, so `obtain` cannot be defined in terms of it. I'm still not entirely sure *why* this scoping rule exists, but this is *what's* going on.